# IF statement, Trouble with formula

Tags: calculated-column

I have created a simple list where we record time spent on troubleshooting customers. But now I would like to create a simple formula for a Calculated field, but I can't get it to work.

We have two hourly rates.

- Number of minutes times 0.75
- Number of minutes times 0.66

What I would like is to select the applicable rate from a dropdown menu and have a calculated field that calculates the number of minutes that need to be charged according to the selected rate.

I have the following fields:

- Minutes (total number of minutes worked)
- Hourly Rate (Rate 0,75 or 0,66)
- Minutes to charge (caluclated automatically)

So the formula should be for instance......:

*If "Hourly Rate" is 0.75 than "Minutes" times 0.75, BUT if "Hourly Rate" is 0.66 than "Minutes" times 0.66...*

I am using Sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with PirateEric that SharePoint will just do the calculation.

That said, you might want to check if the users have selected a rate first. In this case your calculated column would be:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Rate Column]),0,[Rate Column]*[Minutes Column])
```

(output format: number)

Answer (score 1):

If the users are submitting an item and the rate and minutes are fields in the form, then you'd just need to do something like `=[Rate Column]*[Minutes Column]`.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx) is a great reference on calculated columns.